# Sum up numbers each row and column (with awk)?

Tags: awk

is there a way to sum up numbers each row and column to each other, maybe by using awk?
I created a pivot table, also with awk, and need to add the numbers in a row to the numbers of the row above. It's hard for me to describe, so here is an example:

The current table looks like this:
(I need commas as separators)

```
6,3,8,3,1
8,2,7,7,4
9,9,3,1,0
14,11,5,0,0
```

The final result should look like this:

```
6,3,8,3,1
14,5,15,10,5
23,14,18,11,5
37,25,23,11,5
```

So each number gets added up to the number above.
The final table can be a seperate file.

How do I do this?

Comment: Cool, I've edited my question.
@steffen no, 1+4+0+0=5

Comment: Operation you want to use has own name - it is [Cumulative Sum](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CumulativeSum.html)

Comment: @markp-fuso oh, correct, my fault because of the padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { $i = sum[i] += $i; } print}'
6,3,8,3,1
14,5,15,10,5
23,14,18,11,5
37,25,23,11,5
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is yet so easy to read… I would’ve been never be able to write this on my own. Thanks!!